# IS GlusterFS filesystem partition smart enough to shrink in size due to new data on the server?

Tags: filesystems, glusterfs

I'm new to GlusterFS but it works really well for me as a distributed file system. I have a question about my setup and if I should use the partition I store the GlusterFS brick on for anything else. My setup looks like this.

```
Server 1: /external/array1/brick1/
Server 2: /external/array2/brick2/
Server 3: /external/array3/brick3/
```

I then used GlusterFS to make a distributed file system with each brick1,2,3 into one volume to mount.

My question is what happens to GlusterFS if I add something to array1,2,3 where the brick is stored. It is competing for space on the partition. For instance, say I have a constantly growing directory at /external/array1/growing_directory

How would that effect GlusterFS distributed file system. Will it know how to shrink the brick due to the growing directory that is competing with space?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do that. While not required, you want to give GlusterFS bricks their own partition so that you can check their usage via a simple `df -h`.

To answer your question no, GlusterFS does not take into account other data in the same partition as its bricks.